# Same code but different output in Netbeans C/C++ Project

Tags: c++, c, netbeans

I came across this weird situation in Netbeans C/C++. Here is the situation:
In my project explorer, under Source Files, I have main.c and problem3.c

In main.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    // long BigNumber(){
        // return 600851475143;
    // }


    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        printf("%lu", BigNumber() );

        return (EXIT_SUCESS);
    }
```

In problem3.c

```
     long BigNumber(){
         return 600851475143;
     }
```

My case is, when I use BigNumber() from problem3.c, it will output `403282979527`, which is incorrect. But if I use BigNumber() from main.c, it will print `600851475143`.

Can anyone explain the magic behind? Is it because of the platform, or tools such as `make`? I'm using Windows 7 32-bit, NetBeans 7.3.1, with MinGW.

Comment: Trying to do anything with a 32-bit unsigned in larger than 4GB is "undefined behavior"...  ALSO "long != unsigned long".  And a "long" on a 32-bit PC is 32 bits, but a "long" on a 64-bit PC is 64-bits...

Comment: When the compiler compiles `main.c`, how does it know that `BigNumber` returns a `long`?

Comment: @paulsm4, but why the output is different? I actually tried `unsigned long BigNumber()` too, but the result is same.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ah, good point, the old assumed int.  A prototype would likely fix it.

Comment: @TanJiaMing Fix the obvious bugs first. You can't fix everything at the same time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, sorry for my stubbornness, but I don't quite understand your first comment. Can you please tell me more about it?

Comment: @TanJiaMing I'm not sure what it is that you don't understand. My first comment was that when the compiler compiles `main.c`, it would have no way to know that `BigNumber` returns a `long`. What is unclear or confusing about that? My second comment was in response to you claiming you tried fixing an obvious bug and the result was the same. If so, why ask about the code that has an obvious bug that you knew about? Ask about the code that you think has all the bugs fixed so we can help you find a new bug.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, thanks for your hint, I finally got it working. But a direct sentence like "you missed function declaration" would do much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually overflow as Windows 32-bit follows the LP32 or 4/4/4 model where int, long and pointer are all 32-bits (4 bytes) long and the number you are storing is larger than 32-bits, signed or not.  The fact that it works at all in the first case is actually just a coincidence.  Likely the linking step caused by moving it to the other file "brings out" some other behavior that causes the problem you are seeing.  gcc even warns of overflow here.

You have a few options, but a simple one is to use `int64_t` instead of `long` (this is why all those `intxx_t` types exist after all!).  You should also use a LL suffix on the literal to inform the compiler that it is a `long long` literal, and also change your printf to use `"llu"` instead of `"lu"` (`long long` again)

The fix altogether:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int64_t BigNumber() {
    return 600851475143LL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("%llu", BigNumber() );
    return 0;
}
```

You should be able to safely move this function, as it is now well defined.

Comment: Strange, I have tried int64_t, but it is not working, same for the `LL`. Well, I made it work following @DavidSchwartz's hint, which I missed function declarations. I thought it would run nicely, because I actually did the same mistake with previous 2 source files, but they showed no error.